# custom css cannot override bootstrap css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some styles in my custom CSS to override bootstrap CSS, but it seems they can not override bootstrap CSS. When I checked the styles using chrome developer mode I can only see bootstrap styles being applied! 
Here is a screen shot of my chrome bootstrap:[image]

Here is what I have in my css:

```
.panel-default>.panel-heading {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border: 10px solid #b03636;


}
.panel-heading {
    padding: 10px 15px !important;
    border: 10px solid transparent !important;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px !important;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px !important;
}
```

Am I missing anything?
Thanks,

Comment: show us the issue in fiddle/snippet. so that we can easily help to you on that.

Comment: "When I checked the styles using chrome developer mode I can only see bootstrap styles being applied!" —Your screenshot shows that the CSS in your question is being applied though!

Comment: @Quentin as you can see on the screenshot the border of 10 px in my custom CSS has not been applied!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that your **css** file is properly linked or not linked at all to your **HTML** page. You should check that first

Answer (score 2):

Link your CSS file to HTML properly and **import after bootstrap CSS** like below so, you no need to write **!important** for all things to overnight.

```
<link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you should check first: Go through all the styles and see whether the ones in your custom CSS are found at all. If so, they'll likely be crossed out to imply that they were overwritten by the bootstrap styles. If not though, that means that for one reason or another it's not finding your styles at all, and that's where the problem lies.

If they're definitely being overwritten, I might also recommend making sure that the custom CSS is being called *after* the bootstrap files.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your custom CSS is loaded after the Bootstrap CSS file and if it does not help, Use !important attribute with custom CSS to force the overriding.